# get selected information from mysql via dropdown menu

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple drop down menu.

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <select name="mountname">
        <option value="white">white</option>
        <option value="black">black</option>
        <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
        <option value="green">green</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit Pick" />
```

to save what is selected I used.

```
if (!empty($_POST['color'])){

    $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $color = $_POST['color'];

    mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE users SET home_color='".$color."' WHERE id='".$id."'")or die("error  == ----> ".mysqli_error());

    mysqli_close($mysqli);
    header('Location: index.php');
    }
```

saving the color to mysql is no problem.
//update//
      the USER table is set up like this.
    ID, username,password, first_name, last_name, email,home_color

When a user selects his home color, and then submits it it is saved to the db.

ie `1, Bob, MD5pass, Bob,Smith,Bob@bob.com, Black`

`2, Joe, MD5pass, Joe,Doe,joe@Doe.com, Green`

now i have another table called mount. 
 mount has color info in it.
this table hold color name, and info.

```
ID, color_name, color_info
```

the ID is is an INT with A_I.

Bob Logs in and selects his home color saves it to his profile. 
so now when a person goes to bobs profile the will see color info. 
how do I make it where it reads profile info and displays info from another table.

something like the code below. I know the code is wrong, but only way i can explain it.

```
   if (black){
          mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM mount;
         }else{  
             (green)
```

Comment: @YatinMistry, If AJAX is used, Page will be refreshed after submision, so page will not get response result!

Comment: @YatinMistry, Code works, not worried about refresh. I am trying to fig out if John Doe fav color is Black and he has that saved to his profile, I would like to display information about the color black form his profile.

Comment: @DigitalOutcast After update to user save color id into session and when it redirect to index.php show from session

Comment: @DigitalOutcast otherwise if you have user id in session then you will fetch user color info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, color is saved in user's table. Problem is how to fetch color's data from `mount` along with user's data..
On Profile Page, you can get details of user with color by ..

```
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM users u, mount c WHERE u.home_color=c.color_name AND u.id='".$id."'")or die("error  == ----> ".mysqli_error());
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Now, you can manipulate `$result` as it contains users detail as well as color detail! We are getting data from both tables `users` and `mount` by same keys comparision `home_color` of *users* and `color` of *mount*.

If you saved colors in `mount` like 'Black', I'm suggesting you to keep same keyword in `<select>` dropdown, as 'Black' is not equal to 'black'.

Another thing I want to suggest you is, Change your select dropdown to dynamic. Fetch color data from table `mount` and use it like..

```
<select name="mountname">
<?php
$res_colors = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM mount");
$colors = mysqli_fetch_array($res_colors);
foreach($colors as $color){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $color['color']; ?>"><?php echo $color['color']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Best way to use primary key as foreign key, so use ID of `mount` instead of color for dropdown and saving it to user's table.

---

Comment: Sorry to ask can you please explaine the code to me.. I forgot to put the color data is stored in a table called mount.

Comment: As you said, color is saved in user's table. Problem is how to fetch color's data from `mount` along with user's data, right?

Comment: @DigitalOutcast, I've changed my answer, check it and let me know if you get it or not.

Comment: I change my question around I hope it will explain what i am trying to do, Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: My answer still works for you.. as you need detail of color from `mount` table for particular user.... `SELECT * FROM users u, mount c WHERE u.home_color=c.color AND u.id='".$id."'` will fulfill your requirement, here `$id` would be you user's id. If user's own profile, it would be `$_SESSION['id']` otherwise you have variable, as you are already display other details!